# How to access return value from asyntask from another activity in android java

Tags: java, android-asynctask

I need to access asynctask output in another activity .Drawable which is returned in loadImageAsyntask, I need to use it in SpecificActivity class for setting imageview....I have tried but getting null value in specific activity class.Also while moving back from specific activity using back navigation, previous activity is loading again.In previous activity Im doing fetching data through url by parsing json. So when Im clicking back to previous activity, again data is fetching process gets started. I need to avoid loading again instead I need to show the previously loaded data.

```
 public  class LoadImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {
        private Drawable drawable;
        String imageUrl;
        private Drawable image;
        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(imageUrl).getContent();
             Drawable  d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");

                Log.e("drwable",""+d);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Specific Activity", "Converting drawable" + e);

            }
            return  drawable;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable drawableImage) {
            super.onPostExecute(drawableImage);
            setImage(drawableImage);

        }
        public void setImage(Drawable drawable)
        {
            new SpecificNewsReportActivity().drawable=drawable;
            Log.e("set image",""+drawable);
             this.drawable=drawable;
        }
        public Drawable getImage()
        {
            Log.e("get image",""+drawable);

            return drawable;
        }
    }
```

```
public class SpecificNewsReportActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView contentTextView, titleTextView;
    public ImageView imageView;

    private Intent intent;
    public Drawable drawable;
    private String imageUrl;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_specific_news_report);

        ActionBar actionBar=this.getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar!=null)
        {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        intent = getIntent();
        LoadImageAsyncTask task = new LoadImageAsyncTask();
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> d=task.execute();

        try {
            drawable = d.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
        Log.e("drawable specific", "" + drawable);
        drawable=new LoadImageAsyncTask().getImage();
        contentTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.specific_news_report_content_text_view);
        titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.specific_news_report_title_text_view);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.specific_news_report_image_view);
        contentTextView.setText(intent.getStringExtra("content"));
        titleTextView.setText(intent.getStringExtra("title"));
        try {
            if(drawable!=null) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("returned drawable","null");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(" exception", "" + ex);
        }

    }
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home){
            Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: You could just use Glide or Picasso, which are image loading libraries, and will cache the image

Comment: tq @cricket_007 I have displayed my image using picasso..

Comment: Im getting null intent here ```Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);```I need to navigate to back activity

Comment: You're getting a null parent because `new SpecificNewsReportActivity()` never actually sets the parent, and this is not how you are supposed to create a new activity. If you want a result from an Activity, there is `startActivityForResult` method